# A method to find the number of points contained inside the rectangle in O(log n ^2 ) worst case with precomputation?

Tags: algorithms, trees

Given a set of 2 - D points (with integer x and integer  y coordinates) and a set of queries containing the coordinates of a rectangle(integers).

Answer (score 1):

This is called the 2-d orthogonal range counting problem.

Since you mentioned no constraints on the space usage, this can be done with $O(\log\log n)$ query time and $O(n^2)$ space in the RAM model using the predecessor algorithm.

The best small space solution in the RAM model requires $O(\log n/\log\log n)$ query time while taking $O(n\log^2 n)$ space. See the [survey](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/pdf/survey.pdf) by Agarwal and Erickson.